# How to create a reminder on a MarkAsTask item using Microsoft Office Profession Plus 2013?

Tags: vba, outlook

The following macro worked before an upgrade to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

Previous full functionality of this macro:

**Prerequisite:**

For each of the actions (`FlagDayAfterTomorrow`, `FlagNextWeek` etc.), I create an icon in the Quick Access Toolbar of Microsoft Outlook.

For an already sent / received email, I click on one of the referring icons and two things happen:

1. The mail is flagged as a todo item with the referring date
2. At the referring date and at the defined hour the mail appears in the Reminder box.

With Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 only number 1 is working. No Reminder comes up.

**What do I have to do to make #2 work with this version of Outlook?**

```
'**********************************************************
'Declarations section of the module
'**********************************************************
'      Option Explicit

Public Enum FlagWhatEnum
  flNextWeek = 0
  flThisEvening = 1
  flTomorrow = 2
  flDayAfterTomorrow = 3
End Enum

Public Sub FlagNextWeek()
  FlagItem flNextWeek
End Sub

Public Sub FlagThisEvening()
  FlagItem flThisEvening
End Sub

Public Sub FlagTomorrow()
  FlagItem flTomorrow
End Sub
Public Sub FlagDayAfterTomorrow()
  FlagItem flDayAfterTomorrow
End Sub

Public Sub FlagItem(FlagWhat As FlagWhatEnum)
  Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
  Dim Item As Object
  Dim i&
  Dim dt As Date
  Dim tm As String
  Dim Icon As OlMarkInterval

  Select Case FlagWhat
  Case flNextWeek
    dt = DateAdd("d", 7, Date)
    tm = CStr(dt) & " 15:00"
    Icon = olMarkNextWeek
  Case flThisEvening
    dt = Date
    tm = CStr(dt) & " 15:00"
    Icon = olMarkToday
  Case flTomorrow
    dt = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    tm = CStr(dt) & " 15:00"
    Icon = olMarkTomorrow
  Case flDayAfterTomorrow
    dt = DateAddW(Date, 2)
    tm = CStr(dt) & " 15:00"
    Icon = olMarkDayAfterTomorrow
  End Select

  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Explorer Then
    Set Sel = obj.Selection
    For i = 1 To Sel.Count
      Set obj = Sel(i)
      If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = obj
        Mail.MarkAsTask Icon
        Mail.TaskStartDate = tm
        Mail.TaskDueDate = tm
        Mail.Save
      End If
    Next

  Else
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.MailItem Then
      Set Mail = obj
      Mail.MarkAsTask olMarkNextWeek
      Mail.TaskStartDate = tm
      Mail.TaskDueDate = tm
      Mail.Save
    End If
  End If
End Sub

' https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115489
'==========================================================
' The DateAddW() function provides a workday substitute
' for DateAdd("w", number, date). This function performs
' error checking and ignores fractional Interval values.
'==========================================================
Function DateAddW(ByVal TheDate, ByVal Interval)

    Dim Weeks As Long, OddDays As Long, Temp As String

    If VarType(TheDate) <> 7 Or VarType(Interval) < 2 Or _
      VarType(Interval) > 5 Then
        DateAddW = TheDate
    ElseIf Interval = 0 Then
        DateAddW = TheDate
    ElseIf Interval > 0 Then
        Interval = Int(Interval)

        ' Make sure TheDate is a workday (round down).
        Temp = Format(TheDate, "ddd")
        If Temp = "Sun" Then
            TheDate = TheDate - 2
        ElseIf Temp = "Sat" Then
            TheDate = TheDate - 1
        End If

        ' Calculate Weeks and OddDays.
        Weeks = Int(Interval / 5)
        OddDays = Interval - (Weeks * 5)
        TheDate = TheDate + (Weeks * 7)

        ' Take OddDays weekend into account.
        If (DatePart("w", TheDate) + OddDays) > 6 Then
            TheDate = TheDate + OddDays + 2
        Else
            TheDate = TheDate + OddDays
        End If

        DateAddW = TheDate
    Else                          ' Interval is < 0
        Interval = Int(-Interval) ' Make positive & subtract later.

        ' Make sure TheDate is a workday (round up).
        Temp = Format(TheDate, "ddd")
        If Temp = "Sun" Then
            TheDate = TheDate + 1
        ElseIf Temp = "Sat" Then
            TheDate = TheDate + 2
        End If

        ' Calculate Weeks and OddDays.
        Weeks = Int(Interval / 5)
        OddDays = Interval - (Weeks * 5)
        TheDate = TheDate - (Weeks * 7)

        ' Take OddDays weekend into account.
        If (DatePart("w", TheDate) - OddDays) < 2 Then
            TheDate = TheDate - OddDays - 2
        Else
            TheDate = TheDate - OddDays
        End If

        DateAddW = TheDate
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no automatic reminder you can try to set one yourself.

Code is theoretical as all this does not exist in my setup.

```
Mail.TaskStartDate = tm
Mail.TaskDueDate = tm

Mail.ReminderSet = True
Mail.ReminderTime = tm

Mail.SAVE

' A saved ReminderTime does not indicate a reminder will trigger.
' No impact in my setup.
Debug.Print .ReminderTime
```